# Index seems to be out of sync for jQuery .keydown and .click methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to navigate images using both keyboard and mouse (clicking left and right arrow images).

I'm using jQuery to do this, but the shared `imgIndex` seems to be off from the `.keydown` function and the `.click` function. Whenever `.keydown` function `--` or `++` the `imgIndex`, isn't that changed index also used in the click function? So shouldn't they always be on the same index?

**`keydown` function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages($site)) ?>];

$(document).ready(function() {      

    var img = document.getElementById("showimg");
    img.src = imgArray[<?php echo $imgid ?>];
    var imgIndex = <?php echo $imgid ?>;
    alert(imgIndex);

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        var rightarrow = 39;
        var leftarrow = 37;
        var random = 82;
    
        if (key == rightarrow) 
        {
            imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex > imgArray.length-1) 
            {
                imgIndex = 0;

            }
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
        }
        if (key == leftarrow) 
        {
            if (imgIndex == 0) 
            {
                imgIndex = imgArray.length;
            }
            
            img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
        }   
    });
```

**click function:** Connected to left and right clickable images

[image]

```
    $("#next").click(function() {
        imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex > imgArray.length-1) 
            {
                imgIndex = 0;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
    });
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        if (imgIndex == 0) 
            {
                imgIndex = imgArray.length;
            }           
            img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
    });
});

</script>
```

*Just so  you have some visibility into the `getImages` PHP function:*

```
<?php
function  getImages($siteParam) {
include 'dbconnect.php';
if ($siteParam == 'artwork') { 
    $table = "artwork"; 
}       
else { 
    $table = "comics"; 
}   
    
$catResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, path, thumb, views, catidFK FROM $table");   
$img = array();
while($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $img[] = "'" . $row['path'] . "'";
}
return $img;
}
?>
```

Much appreciated!

Snapshot of where the script is on "view image.php"

[image]

Comment: I retagged this because it showed up as a php question, in reality seems to be a JS question. Anyways, could you set up a jsfiddle for us to play with? It's easier to visualize longer bits of code like that

Comment: If your `.click` functions are within your `$(document).ready` as well, then there is no reason why this shouldn't work. As @KaviSiegel suggested, a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) reproducing the problem would help a lot (just add dummy values for the bits that come from PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are defining the imgIndex as a local variable inside the 'ready' handler, and try to use as a global. In this case both prev/next handlers will get their own copies of imgIndex.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/f2WzJ/

```
var imgArray = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5'];
var imgIndex = 3;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $("#imgIndex");
    $img.text(imgIndex);
    //alert(imgIndex);

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        var rightarrow = 39;
        var leftarrow = 37;
        var random = 82;

        if (key == rightarrow) {
            imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex > imgArray.length - 1) {
                imgIndex = 0;

            }
            //img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
             $img.text(imgIndex);
        }
        if (key == leftarrow) {
            if (imgIndex == 0) {
                imgIndex = imgArray.length;
            }

            //img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
            $img.text(--imgIndex);
        }
    });

    $("#next").click(function() {
        imgIndex++;
        if (imgIndex > imgArray.length - 1) {
            imgIndex = 0;
        }
        $img.text(imgIndex);
        //img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
    });
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        if (imgIndex == 0) {
            imgIndex = imgArray.length;
        }
        $img.text(--imgIndex);
        //img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
    });
});​
```

Comment: I thought that may have been the issue too, but they're still out of sync.

Comment: @Growler, check the fiddle I created.

Comment: why did you replace  img.src = imgArray[imgIndex]; with $img.text(imgIndex);? And, img.src let's me display the image to an html id... what's the jquery equivalent? Your solution allows me to display the text. Thank you very much btw

Comment: @Growler, I did that just to get it working on jsFiddle, sorry if I miss led you. You should use your code with img.src in your application. I only tried to demonstrate that imgIndex is now properly synced. Please uncomment your code and and delete my $img.text() line

Comment: Ah, understood. But can you explain the difference between img.src(index) and $img.src(index). Is the $ a special jquery character for variables?

Comment: @Growler, no it's not a special character. But it's a convention used for jQuery extended elements (i.e elements you retrieve using $() method.) Specialty is elements returned by $() are extended with jQuery methods which are not present on elements returned from document.getElementById(). So in order to indicate that a variable holds a jQuery object, by convention those variable names begin with $. Other than that there is no use of $ character.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=element look here to get some idea on what kind of extended methods are added to DOM elements by jQuery.

Comment: Hi Buddhi, It still doesn't seem to be synching up. Can we chat via e-mail or something?

Comment: @Growler, do you have your site publicly available? Did you go through my fiddle? Can you replicate the problem on my fiddle as well? or do you just see it in your code?

Comment: The site was launched today :D Enjoy the comics! http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/   There you can see for yourself (click on a comic to view the full size) that the arrow keys and clicking the keys are out of sync

Comment: @Growler, Good comics! Do you still have that script on page? Can you move it on to a different file and refer it on the head so its easier to find.

Comment: Thanks! The code is on the "viewimage" page. I've updated my post above with the location

Comment: @Growler, As far as I can see it is synced. But you have prev and next spans mixed up. So when you click next counter goes down, and for prev counter goes up. Could that be your problem?

Comment: BTW, you should not use spans for this for umpteen amount of reasons, use a tags instead, so it can work even when JS is disabled. (Changing SPANs to A alone will not fix that issue, you will need little bit of coding)

Comment: OMG I had the prev and next spans mixed up this whole time?! I'm such a dummy :( And what do you mean use "tags" instead of SPAN?

Comment: @Growler, :) don't worry, that sort of things happens to anyone. I meant to say you should use "a tags", that is hyperlinks <a href="/img/file.jpg">Next</a> like that

Answer (score 0):

If your handling of click and keypress go in different

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

block then the variables would not be shared. This is because the code in that block is treated as anonymous function and any variable you declare in there would be scooped to that block.